# Как в django сделать передачу координат мыши с канвы в бд и обратно?

Tags: python, ajax, django

**Здравствуйте!**

Бьюсь пятый (!) день, пожалуйста, подскажите. Не могу решить проблему передачи координат из канвы в базу django и обратно.

Вот такая рисовалка схем на django. Пока рисуем просто линии, но эти линии надо сохранить в базе. То есть я рисую, она должна сразу сохраняться:

**canvas.js:**

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var raf;
var running = false;
var mouseOldPos;
var mousePos;

var wallLine = {
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouseOldPos.x, mouseOldPos.y);
    ctx.lineTo(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

function clear() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  ctx.lineWidth = 10.0; 
  ctx.lineCap = 'square';
  if (running) {
    clear();
    mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    wallLine.draw();
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!running) {
    mouseOldPos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    running = true;

  } else {
    running = false;
  }

});

function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
      x: e.clientX - rect.left,
      y: e.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
```

**Шаблон plan_detail.html:**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Name: {{ plan.name }}</h1>
  <strong>Architect:</strong> {{ plan.architect }}</p>
  <p><strong>Approved:</strong> {{ plan.approved }}</p>
  <p><strong>num_elements:</strong> {{ num_elements }}</p>
  <p><strong>Approve Date:</strong> {{ plan.approve_date }}</p>  
  {% if perms.catalog.can_edit_plan %}
      <a href="{% url }">Edit</a>  
  {% endif %}
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid" width="1000" height="700"></canvas>
  {% load static %}   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/canvas.js' %}"></script>

  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Как видите выше, я пытался связать все это через скрипт на странице со скриптом в файле, но не вышло.

**Модель в models.py** для всех линий всех схем:

```
class Element(models.Model):
"""Element - it's wall or smth else on the axis. Between axises"""
#axis_owner = models.ForeignKey(Axis, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='axis_owner') # need for slanted axises???
plan_id = models.UUIDField(null=True, blank=True)
axis_id = models.IntegerField()
x0 = models.IntegerField()
y0 = models.IntegerField()
x1 = models.IntegerField()
y1 = models.IntegerField()
# for explicitly specify alignment. By default alignment define automatically:

ALIGN = (
    ('l', 'Left'),
    ('r', 'Right'),
    ('c', 'Center'),
    ('a', 'Auto'),
)

align = models.CharField(
    max_length=1,
    choices=ALIGN,
    blank=True,
    default='c',
    help_text='You can explicitly specify alignment option. Default = Auto',
)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Element, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the Model object."""
    return self.axis_id
```

**строчка в urls.py:**

```
path('plan/<uuid:pk>/', views.canvasData, name='plan-detail'),
```

**Функция в views.py:**

```
def canvasData(request, pk):
"""View function for elements rendering on canvas"""
context = {

}
return render(request, 'catalog/plan_detail.html', context=context)
```

Где pk - это pk схемы (plan_id в классе Element ), каждая схема имеет свой набор этих самых линий.

В итоге моя штука должна выглядеть примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю, что надо применять ajax, но я не представляю как это сделать, все примеры что есть в сети только вводят меня в заблуждение. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Вы же не собираетесь передавать координаты мыши на сервер ежемоментно?

Comment: Рекомендуемый интервал между отправками на сервер через ajax - 5 сек. Если сервер отвечает быстро, то можно сделать 2-3 сек., но вы должны быть уверены, что сервер будет успевать реагировать. Джанго не отличается особой скоростью. Например, отклик djangoproject.org составляет 1.5-1.8 сек.

Comment: Вообще-то собирался одномоментно, но я догадывался, что будут проблемы. Поскольку процесс должен быть такой: инженер компании рисует схему, а изменения в ней онлайн видит клиент компании. Инженер начертил линию, или изменил ее, а клиент говорит, так или не так, может переставить эту линию... И да, не координаты мыши, а всего 4 координаты: начало и конец линии. То есть процесс рисования линии онлайн передавать не требуется

Comment: Хотя, если будут проблемы, можно какой-то кусок схемы редактировать локально, и лишь потом отправлять на сервер.

Comment: ну можно попробовать django channels vs websockets. Это наиболее оптимально. Не будет работать только на ie8 и ниже

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, решил вопрос просмотром вот этого видео https://youtu.be/9QNw5v6BUBE, хотя не люблю видеоуроки. Пока работает на локалке, как на боевом будет, не знаю.